# Why is __debug__ not in the keywords list when it's a keyword?

Tags: python, keyword, python-internals

`__debug__` is a built-in constant, which, according to the [docs on constants](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html), doesn't seem like an implementation detail.

When trying to assign to it (which isn't supported as the docs state) the following error message is displayed:

```
>>> __debug__ = False
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: assignment to keyword
```

Apparently, according to the message, it's a keyword, but:

```
>>> from keyword import kwlist
>>> '__debug__' in kwlist
False
```

Which seems odd. `None`, `True` and `False`, also listed as constants, are contained in the `kwlist`.

Why isn't `__debug__` in the keyword list?

Comment: It's a constant not keyword. `def`, `class` etc are keywords.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary hm, what about `True`, `False` and `None`, then?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: `__debug__` does look like an oversight here.

Comment: The documentation, however does state: [The names None, False, True and __debug__ cannot be reassigned (assignments to them, even as an attribute name, raise SyntaxError), so they can be considered “true” constants.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__)

Comment: Seems like the documentation makes it fairly clear that this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @idjaw I'm not wondering why I can't assign to it. Wandering why it isn't in `kwlist` when the error message states it's a keyword.

Comment: @BobHolver It's quite likely the error you see is a result of someone not wanting to create a new error message just for this special case.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ according to the check made in [`ast.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/11e97f2f80bf65cc828c127eafc95229df35d403/Python/ast.c#L945) this doesn't seem like the case. I would be happier if this simply stated that you can't assign to `__debug__`, i.e `__debug__` not assignable.

Comment: I think @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is essentially right. Based on [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/70f52768fd1070b457d674bed368c69cb4a7483c), it looks like `__debug__` was checked alongside other keywords for simplicity, then people realised that had to change, and some slightly lazy copy pasting was done rather than thinking of a new error message.

Comment: @AlexHall Colour me impressed. Not sure how you found that commit in the sea of commits on that repository.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I looked at the link the others posted, hit 'Blame', went to the line, looked at the latest commit for that line, saw it was irrelevant, and clicked 'View blame prior to this change'. Basically lets you see the history of a line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's technically not a keyword in the sense of the Python grammar. There's a [specific check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/11e97f2f80bf65cc828c127eafc95229df35d403/Python/ast.c#L945) in the compiler that prevents assignment to `__debug__`, but as far as the grammar is concerned, `__debug__` isn't a keyword, and `keyword.kwlist` is generated from the grammar.